# Conflicts in routing in symfony between bundles

Tags: symfony

Playing around with symfony. I have two bundles and each bundle has a controller within it. Just to see how routing works I gave the same path to functions within both controllers. Bundle B was the newly created bundle and when the URL app/simple was hit I got a response from bundle B always. Just curious as to whether there is any logic behind this.

PS: I know this is bad practice but just wanted to see how the guts of routing in works.

```
/**
 * @Route("/app/simple", name="homepage")
 */
 public function indexAction()
{
    return new Response('Hello From bundle A!');
}
```

In bundle B

```
/**
 * @Route("/app/simple", name="homepage")
 */
 public function indexAction()
{
    return new Response('Hello From bundle B!');
}
```

Comment: I will depends as to the order that they are in your route collection which would be defined by your routing files. The routing component will choose the first matching route which, I assume, in your case would be from Bundle B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app has a single routing configuration which can include other configurations. Probably `app/config/routing.yml`.

That configuration file will include the routes for your bundles by using the `resource` key that can import routes from another `routing.yml` file or from annotations in a PHP controller.

The order of those will determine which route gets chosen since Symfony2 always uses the first matching route.